# How to change directory and run command on that directory?

Tags: java, cmd

Example: I want to change directory to : C:/temp/hacking/passsword
and execute a command like that : java Helloworld arg1 arg2
How can I do this with java?

Comment: What do you mean by "change directory"?  Does your program keep track of a "current directory"?

Comment: Type `Help` in the command prompt. For each command listed type `help <command>` (eg `help dir`) or `<command> /?` (eg `dir /?`).  `cd C:\temp\hacking\passsword` then `c:\FolderJavaInstalledIn\java Helloworld Arg1 arg2`. `\` is the path separator in windows.

Comment: A Java program is not a shell. While there's a "current directory" (the value of the `user.dir` system property), you provide the working directory to each process you launch using `Runtime` or `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: I'm writing Java program to execute cmd command to change my current directory to another drive and execute a command .More clear?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    Process pr = builder.start();
    String[] commands = {"commands"};
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    builder = builder.directory(new File(/one/two/dir));
    pr = builder.start();
```

Or if you prefer this approach:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\Test\" && dir");

    Process pr = builder.start();
```

There are several other questions similar to this one here on SO, I suggest you also go check them out to get a better idea.

Comment: Actually, you cannot run `cd` as it is a shell builtin, and even if you could, it would apply only to the subprocess. It would not carry over back to the Java program or subsequent subprocesses that you launched.

Comment: I do not think running `cd` with `Runtime.exec()` will have any effect on subsequent calls.

Comment: Sorry, I got a little confused, the ProcessBuilder will work.